# Date Functions in hibernate 5 HQL

Tags: hibernate-5

So I'm kind of new to hibernate, hence just bear with me here. I have a mysql query like so:

```
SELECT SUM(PLAN_ID), USER_ID 
FROM   TABLE_A 
WHERE  ACTIVATION_DATE 
         BETWEEN DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
             AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
AND    USER_ID in ('123','124') GROUP BY '123';
```

I'm trying to run the same using the hibernate 5 JPQL query. This is what I've tried:

```
Map<Integer, List<Object>> result = null;
Query query = null;
Session session = null;
session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
result = new HashMap<Integer, List<Object>>();
query = session.createQuery(aggregationQuery);
int rowNo = 0;
for (Iterator it = query.iterate(); it.hasNext();) {
rowNo ++;
result.put(rowNo, (List<Object>) it.next());
}
```

Yet it throws `Unexpected token errors`. Would someone mind explaining what im doing wrong here?
Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use them as they are because JPQL does not know them.

You have two options:

1) use SQL

```
session.createNativeQuery(aggregationQuery);
```

2) use the JPQL function

```
function('DATE_ADD', function('LAST_DAY', function('DATE_SUB', current_date, function('INTERVAL', 2, 'MONTH')), function('INTERVAL' 1, DAY)
```

Option 2 is not working code it's just and example to show you where this could lead. You probably use better option 1 with the native query.